# How to deleting selected range of cells when range is dependent on a variable?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to delete the cells in the range `G123:P10000`, but the value of `123` in `G123` keeps on changing, so how can I provide the variable while providing range.

Below can be used a one time, but I want to use it multiple times based on the value in the variable named 'count' which changes for every run so that it deletes from that range only

```
Range("G123:P10000").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

I tried something like below, but its not working

```
count = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Range("G$count:P10000").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: Use `Range("G" & count & ":O500").Select`

Comment: 1) `Range("G" & count & ":P10000").Select` 2) [How to determine last used row/column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) 3) [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [`.Offset()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) and [`.Resize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff193274.aspx) modifications for range.

```
...
count = CountRows(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))
ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Offset(count,0).Resize(10000-count,1).ClearContents
```

with

```
Public Function CountRows(ByVal r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```